# How to attach object to existing property using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I have a property that contains a list from an entity in my model. I want to add an item to this list but when I do, it's added as detached. How can I add this object as attached?

```
using (var db = new fsEntities())
{
   var list = db.Products.Where(x => x.ID == 1).ToList();
   var p = new Product { Description = "New Item", Amount = 14};
   list.Add(p);   //the new item EntityState is detached
}
```

I know I can do this, `db.AddToProducts(p)`, but in my scenario I want to add the object to the existing property with it's `EntityState` as attached, then later perform a `SaveChanges` if necessary.

How can I do this?

Comment: Its usual when you are adding new object - it is in `Detached` state by default. Only in Insert method that generates for you EntityState changed to `Added`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [attach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.attach.aspx) the entity. This will be added to the context with `Unchanged` state.

```
using (var db = new fsEntities())
{
   var list = db.Products.Where(x => x.ID == 1).ToList();
   var p = new Product { Description = "New Item", Amount = 14};

   db.Attach(p);

   list.Add(p);   //the new item EntityState is detached
}
```

Comment: Actually, my problem was getting the new item's entity state to be "added" instead of "detached". This does what I need it to do.        db.Products.AddObject(item);
list.Add(item);